# How to create an internal database

Tags: database-design

Games, such as Nintendo DS games, have to store data of their objects, for example, RPG needs to store data of bestiary, weapons and spells.

I want to know the best way to create a game database in C++ and use object-oriented features.

---

**Example:**

A RPG with the following tables:

- Class (Name, Race, Ability, Atk, Def, ...)
- Race (Name, ...)
- Ability (Name, ...)
- Skill (Name, Race, Power, ...)
- Learning (Class, Level, Skill, ...)

Each class belongs to a race. "Human ranger" and "Elf ranger" are different classes. A class is not available to all races.
Abilities are used outside battles (thieves can lockpick doors), and skills are for battles.
Skills are invented by a race, but other races can learn it. A "human karateka" can learn "Tiger Fist Attack" from "cat men".
A class can learn new skills when level up.

The player can hire mercenaries, that are randomly generated. Mercenaries data is stored in player's save file.

- Mercenary (Name, Class, Level, Personality, ...)

---

It could be stored as static data. Each table could be stored as an array of structs, where the array index is the key of each line in the table.

I would have to create a function to initialize each array position with data of each line. But I think that it can be statically initialized in memory without a function.

An easy way to edit database is important, because many attribute values need to be tested and balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It is the most widely distributed embedded database and integrates very well into many languages.

As your posts begins to explain, you could accomplish this yourself with your own C++ code, but SQLite solves the problem very well and you get many advantages out of the box (sorting, aggregating, etc).